# Visual Studio replace tab with 4 spaces?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to set TAB button to work as 4 spaces in Visual Studio 2010 instead of going to Edit->Advanced->Untabify Selected Lines?

Comment: +1 since within the question there is the hint how to *untabify* already existent sources, the accepted answer applies only for *new* sources

Comment: Would somebody mind editing the "2010" out of the question title? This is applicable to many visual studio versions, and the UI is still the same for this part of the IDE for VS 2010, 2013, and 2015. Also it might help to add something to the question that implies that the OP is looking to set the style of new sources; the trick for editing existing sources is cool though.

Comment: Also note that "Tabify" and "Untabify" for existing source code files does not work for tabs inserted in the middle of the line, i.e., `<tab> int <tab> x;` would be replaced with `<spaces> int <tab> x;`, not `<spaces> int <spaces> x;`

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Community for Mac and instead of untabify, I did Edit>Format>Format Document.

Answer (score 423, accepted):

You can edit this behavior in:

```
Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->Tabs
```

Change Tab to use "Insert Spaces" instead of "Keep Tabs".

Note you can also specify this per language if you wish to have different behavior in a specific language.

Comment: Just to share that is still the same for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What about tab size and indent size?

Comment: @Magallo it's in the same settings area

Comment: In mine what took me so long to find the setting was the fact that theres a checkbox that hides half the settings. be sure to check show all settings

Comment: Just to share that is still the same for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You can specify number of spaces by entering "Indent size" value. 2 or 4 (default), for example

Comment: This is still the same for Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I cannot find this option in Visual Studio Community for Mac. :(

Comment: But if you make a new line, it still puts a tab?

Comment: Hit Ctr-k,Ctr-D to convert to tabs code that you pasted in from another source.

Comment: @Magallo It looks like "Tab size" tells it how many spaces wide a tab character should be rendered, and "Indent size" is how many space characters to enter when you are using spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: Well... This is "almost" still the same in VS 2019... if you already done that and seems not to work, go to:  Tools > Options, and then Text Editor > Advanced > Uncheck "Use adaptive formatting" as seen [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/847853/visual-studio-20194-c-insert-spaces-instead-of-tab.html)

Comment: Where is the "tools"?

Comment: Couldn't find anything like that in VS2020. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not enough.

Comment: For me I had to do the same for `Text Editor > C/C++ (VisualGDB) > Tab > Insert spaces`

Answer (score 19):

First set in the following path Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->Tabs
if still didn't work modify as mentioned below
Go to Edit->Advanced->Set Indentation ->Spaces

Comment: Where is the tools

Comment: You can find it in the menu bar at the top of Visual Studio. Or else even you can press Ctrl+Q and type Tools in the search box

Comment: Tools did't wiork for me, Edit does. Thank you!!

Answer (score 14):

For VS2010 and above ([VS2010 needs a plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8bccfe2-650c-4b42-bc5c-845e21f96328)).
If you have checked/set the options of the tab size in Visual Studio but it still won't work. Then check if you have a **.editorconfig** file in your project! This will override the Visual Studio settings. Edit the tab-size in that file.

This can happen if you install an Angular application in your project with the Angular-Cli.

[See MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/12/15/code-style-configuration-in-the-vs2017-rc-update/)

Answer (score 9):

None of these answer were working for me on my macbook pro. So what i had to do was go to:

Preferences -> Source Code -> Code Formatting -> C# source code.

From here I could change my style and spacing tabs etc. This is the only project i have where the lead developer has different formatting than i do. It was a pain in the butt that my IDE would format my code different than theirs.

Comment: This is correct in Visual Studio for Mac 8.4 (that goes with Unity 2019.2)

Answer (score 7):

For Visual Studio 2019 users:

By the comment under accepted answer, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167033/visual-studio-replace-tab-with-4-spaces/14167067#comment106002654_14167067):

> Well... This is "almost" still the same in VS 2019... if you already done that and seems not to work, go to: Tools > Options, and then Text Editor > Advanced > Uncheck "Use adaptive formatting" as seen here

Comment: The doc below helped me
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-all-languages-tabs?view=vs-2019

Comment: This is really helpful. Visual Studio always automatically replaces tab with spaces for me. That is a bit annoying

Answer (score 6):

If you don't see the formatting option, you can do Tools->Import and Export settings to import the missing one.

Comment: can't find it in version 2022. This solved it anyway. Great 2nd method

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Options >Text Editor > Advanced > Uncheck “Use adaptive formatting”
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tab-will-not-enter-spaces-in-file-with-mixed-inden/1267780

Answer (score 1):

In my Microsoft Visiual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.11.20, there is a file status line at the right bottom corner of the file window, it looks like:

```
Ln: 15  Ch: 3   TABS    CRLF
```

Besides changing `Tabs` option under `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor` to `Insert spaces`. I also need to mannually change the `TABS` in the file status line to `Spaces` by clicking on it. Then it looks like

```
Ln: 15  Ch: 3   SPC     CRLF
```

Instead of clicking the file status line, you can also change this in navigation bar `Edit -> Advanced -> Set Indentation -> Spaces`.

Answer (score 0):

File->Preferences->Settings->'Search Settings'SearchBarAtTheTop='tab size'

Help->About shows:
Visual Studio Code Version: 1.78.2 (user setup)
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Date: 2023-05-10

Comment: This question is for Visual Studio not Visual Studio Code