# GitHub breaks Visual Studio indentation

Tags: visual-studio, github, indentation

I wonder why my code gets messy after I push it to GitHub.
For example, when I indent members of some class, so they are all aligned it looks nice in Visual Studio and ugly in GitHub.

Here is an example:

[image: Indentation in Visual Studio]

And how it looks in GitHub:

[Indentation in GitHub](https://gist.github.com/razzorflame/ef776ddef260608bc1a8799090af629e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure all your indent as actual tabs, not spaces.

Second, by default, GitHub would display tabs as 8 characters.
So try and see the same GitHub page, but adding at the end of its URL: `?ts=4`

That is:

https://gist.github.com/razzorflame/ef776ddef260608bc1a8799090af629e?ts=4

[image: tabs looks good]

Or... [configure your Visual Studio to use a tab width of 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167067/6309) (not ideal though).

---

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33831598/6309), you can add a `.editorconfig` (like [this one](https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/f4b01ff4a2f8e6faead1) for gist) with:

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

# Matches multiple files with brace expansion notation
[*.{js,jsx,html,sass}]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Then GitHub should display tabs using the right width (4).

---

As an illustration of the use of `.editorconfig`, Git itself, with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), tells `.editorconfig` that in this project, `*.txt` files are indented with tabs.

See [commit 7047f75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7047f75f2275d1d84ef2f15f01c99ca890119719) (05 Jan 2020) by [Hans Jerry Illikainen (`illikainen`)](https://github.com/illikainen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 34246a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34246a1a3ca7eb50229e93b0dda799f0abe92cc4), 30 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`editorconfig`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7047f75f2275d1d84ef2f15f01c99ca890119719): indent text files with tabs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Hans Jerry Illikainen</sup>
>
> Previously, the `.editorconfig` did not specify an indentation style for text files.
>
> However, a quick look for indentation-like spacing suggest that tabs are more common for documentation:
>
> ```
> $ git grep -Pe '^ {4}' -- '*.txt' |wc -l 
> 2683 
> $ git grep -Pe '^\t' -- '*.txt' |wc -l 
> 14011
> ```
>
> Note that there are a lot of files that indent list continuations (and other things) with a single space -- if the first search was made without the fixed quantifier the result would look very different.
>   However, the result does correspond with my anecdotal experience when editing Git documentation.
>
> This commit adds `*.txt` to `.editorconfig` as an extension that should be indented with tabs.

Comment: Wow, thats nice! Is there way to set a default "ts=4" in my repo? People who will read my code won't consider using this and they will suffer from seeing unreadable code.
Edit: I am using tabs as indentation always.

Comment: @razzorflame Not sure for gist, but try with adding a `.editorconfig`. See my edited answer.